# c# async udp server closes after initiating

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, udp

i am new at coding, especially with async, and have been trying to implement it for the first time on a udp server for a game im working on(1v1's).
In a synchronous udp server, the code stops when we do receivefrom, so how can i do the same in async? Currently the console goes through the method GetConnection() and simply closes, instead of waiting for a client. Help please.

```
// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket clientSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}


class UDPServer
{
    Socket serverSocket;
    IPEndPoint localIPEP;
    IPEndPoint senderIPEP;
    EndPoint sender;

    IPEndPoint[,] playerList; 
    int playerListIndex;

    bool waitingForSecondClient;

    public UDPServer(IPEndPoint serverIpEndPoint)
    {
        localIPEP = serverIpEndPoint;
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);

        serverSocket.Bind(localIPEP);

        senderIPEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        sender = senderIPEP;

        playerList = new IPEndPoint[5000, 2]; // 5000 possible player lobbies, each with 2 player ip addresses and ports
        playerListIndex = 0; // we start filling up the lobbies from 0
        Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete.");
    }

    public void GetConnection()
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new client.");
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None,ref sender, ClientConnected, state);
    }

    public void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)asyncResult;
        EndPoint remote = state.clientSocket.LocalEndPoint;
        StateObject tempState = new StateObject();
        int bytesReceived = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref remote);
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(tempState.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref remote, ClientConnected, tempState);


        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Received bytes of data: " + bytesReceived);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Received string: " + state.sb.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("-------------");

        if (state.sb.ToString().Equals("New client"))
        {
            Send(state.clientSocket, "Hello");
        }
    }

    private void Send(Socket client,string message)
    {
        EndPoint remote = client.LocalEndPoint;

        StateObject state = new StateObject();

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        serverSocket.BeginSendTo(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,remote,SendCallback,state);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
        Socket client = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
        int bytesSent = client.EndSendTo(asyncResult);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UDPServer server = new UDPServer(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050));
        server.GetConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your application still needs an application loop to keep the process alive while the server socket is responding.  The loop thread doesn't do anything other than wait on something like a volatile flag which can be set by an exception handler for instance or some other signal to instruct the server to shut down cleanly. Not sure if there have been better developments in .Net, but from memory the app loop would just do a Thread.Sleep(1000) to check the flag state every second. A good place to start would be check out examples for C# & DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly solve your problem, but have you looked at `System.IO.Pipelines`? It was designed precisely to help with the handling of asynchronous streams with the async/await paradigm.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/07/09/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/